# MapNetworkDrive will accept any password

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, wsh

I am writing a script for adding a network share to windows laptops provided for students at the school i work at.

The script is written in VBS, and uses the MapNetworkDrive function, so it is very simple, just two dialogs asking for username and password. But when I test it with my own username it seams to completely ignore the password I enter and, presumably, use a password stored somewhere, as it allways maps the drive. Does anyone know where these credentials are stored in windows 7? (It is not stored in credential storage, i checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials aren't *stored* anywhere at all. Rather, Windows is using the credentials of the currently logged-in user to authenticate the connection to the shared resource. That is to say, if the user name and password of the user currently logged in to the *local* machine matches a user with the appropriate credentials on the *remote* machine, access will be granted.

Let me see if I can explain that more clearly with an example. Say I'm logged in to my laptop with the user name "Cody Gray" and the password "1234". Then, I try to initiate a connection to a shared resource on my desktop computer. Since I have the same user name and password on my desktop computer, and that user account has sufficient privileges to connect to shared resources remotely, I'll be automatically authenticated and access will be automatically granted. However, if I try to connect to one of my coworkers' machines, on which I do not have an account, I'll be required to provide a user name and password with valid access credentials.

The user name and password you supply to the WSH `MapNetworkDrive` method are used *only* if the credentials of the currently logged-in user failed to authenticate successfully. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6.aspx) says:

> *strUser*
>
> > Optional. String value indicating the user name. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the credentials of someone other than the current user.
>
> *strPassword*
>
> > Optional. String value indicating the user password. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the credentials of someone other than the current user.

In short, for testing purposes, you might create a new account on your computer that doesn't correspond directly to an account on the server. And if the students already have accounts on the server, there's no reason to require them to enter their user name and password again; Windows already knows what it is, and it will be used for authentication automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I didn't know that it will check the credentials of the local user first, even if strPassword is provided, but in the test I am doing it should not work. The local user has the same username, but the password is different. Any idea what might be happening then?

Comment: @Dimse: Hmm, no idea. A different password should prevent you from connecting. The two accounts have different passwords, yet you get automatically connected? Are you already connected to a *different* network resource from the same server? If that's the case, you won't need authentication, either. Another option is to try WMI instead of the `MapNetworkDrive` function. You'll need something like `ConnectServer`. It takes similar arguments and works a similar way, so it may not work for you either.

Comment: I should not be connected, when I run net use /DELETE * It tells me there are no active connections, but I have been connected previously, maybe it remembers password from then. Thank you, will try using WMI when I get back to work :)